# Indirectly restarting a node.js app

Tags: node.js

I'm writing a node app, to be more specific, it's a chat bot for Discord. It is still a really unstable build so some functions bug out sometimes and to fix those I have to manually restart the bot from my command line.

There are like 20 people on the chat server and everyone is actively using the bot, so whenever it encounters a bug, they ask me to restart it and it gets pretty annoying. (I'm still a greenhorn with node, so debugging those will take a while)

Note: The bot does NOT crash completely, it's that some functions stop working properly, while others still work just fine.

So what I'm wondering:

Is there a way to make my script restart internally?
The bot works with commands written in chat, and what I'm trying to do is make everyone using the bot be able to restart it on command, without having to contact me to do it manually.

Comment: if your application can handle requests from your users (i mean after encountering a bug), you can run next command `process.exit(1);`

Comment: for example,  app can parse all messages from chat and if it find a special word (e.g. "restart") application does exit `process.exit(1);` and you can use forever [https://github.com/foreverjs/forever] to restart crashed application

Comment: Yes, the bot automatically parses every message and only reacts to commands with a prefix character (eg: "!"). I will try your suggestion. Thanks.